# Why not build Essence Reaver on Ashe?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've never seen a recommended build which includes Essence Reaver on Ashe, but I can't work out why.

80 AD, 10% life steal, 10% CDR plus the mana regen means you can leave her Q on permanently during teamfights... why isn't it a perfect item for Ashe?

I understand it's not the best first item, as Infinity Edge makes sense with her passive, but for mid-game sustain and perma-Q teamfights, I'm not sure what I'm missing that means it's not worthwhile.

So why not Essence Reaver on Ashe? What are the drawbacks, or is it simply that other items are more effective?

Comment: Would the person who downvoted please explain why? I can understand that you may think ER on Ashe is a bad idea, but surely that merits an answer explaining why, rather than a downvote?

Answer (score 5):

> the mana regen means you can leave her Q on permanently during teamfights

You can do that without Essence Reaver.

You won't be able to finish Essence Reaver during the laning phase. When the laning phase is over your manapool will be large enough due to your natural stat increase.

Bloodthirster give you better stats for the gold and the build path is identical.

Comment: What else would you use for the mana regen, though? I find Ashe to be mana hungry when using her W for poke and Q to help control teamfights

Comment: You don't need items for mana. Learn to manage it better. the butcher and feast masteries help a lot in lane. i pick them on every botlane AD. You won't be able to finish ER during the laning phase anyways.

Comment: Not to mention there really isn't any need to have Ashe's Q on at all times. You really only need the slow to disengage and chase, your teammates should be the ones CC'ing in teamfights, not you.

Comment: @Yuuki `your teammates should be the ones CC'ing in teamfights, not you` that's a bad attitude. Your Q might save a teammates life!

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW Yes, but you shouldn't dedicate a sub-optimal item when CC'ing isn't your job in the first place. It's like sacrificing damage for more health in an MMORPG on the off chance the tank dies and you need to absorb a few hits. Sure, it may help but you're better off getting the extra damage.

Comment: Essence river would be completely overkilled.
For the lining phase, if you have mana masteries, then you should be fine. You shouldn't activate Q except in TF and in line when fighting, or getting ganked etc.

Comment: @Yuuki did you realise I recommend NOT building ER? :D

Comment: @Yuuki - I find Ashe's Q to be very effective for CC in teamfights and skirmishes - whoever you're focusing has a much harder time escaping, while the hard CC is focused on whoever needs it most.

Comment: I have only ever built the item in question when i built manamune and that was just an experiment so yeah you really do not need the item on ashe. Hell building manamume on ashe is a bad idea aswell but I was trying it out and thought it would be fun however if i had been playing against skilled opponents that build would not have been very good. Think of it this way. Ashe is weak as in squashy so she does not want to be too close to the enemy team essence reaver favors you if you are constantly attack and in close proximity with the enemy team. So the item does not fit with Ashe.

Answer (score 2):

Teamfights shouldn't last all that long, and unless you unloaded all of your mana on your ult and w, BT would help to keep you alive better and you don't have really super important skills for the 10 CDR.  If you're really fed, then I guess you can go ahead, but BT is a better choice.

Comment: I do tend to be quite w happy pre-team fight. I find it gives quite good AoE harass/poke, as even if the enemy team are dodging there's a good chance of hitting one of them. I maybe need to cut that down a little, eg only poke when I have over half my mama available, that way I always have ult plus a w for burst plus a for the team fight/chase/kiting. There's certainly food for thought in your answer though

Answer (score 1):

I almost always build ER on my ADC's because of 2 reasons:  lifesteal and sustainable ability-use.  The damage on ER is decent, and frankly, an ADC needs lifesteal.  I always kit my ADC up to deal lots of damage and extremely high lifesteal - always over 33%.  BOTRK, ER, BT, plus the little bit you can get via Runes/Masteries.  Then, Crit items, 1 or 2 of which should also provide movement speed buffs.  So IE as the main crit-damage item (always) and then the other 2 spots are situational but 1 MUST have a movement speed buff.

I typically look to deal damage and to risk my squishy champ on my ability to position properly and do tons of damage while getting massive health back per hit.  The latest version of Ashe is even more of a beast now, so I think that Black Cleaver is a must on her as a 6th item.  Look to get the dragon speed buff to supplement the loss of another movement item taken over by BC choice.  BC isn't the last item, I'm just saying that it is a critical item to take on her to make her freaking OP.  Trust me, a combination of BOTRK with BC and IE is so fearsome on Ashe now that almost any tank will only Face-check you once after you have that combination - they'll learn a hard lesson if you're good with Ashe (good = positional intelligence as a minimum requirement)

Comment: While a new answer to this question is valuable due to the Ashe changes, I think this answer would be better if it refocused on what advantages and disadvantages there are specifically to buying Essence Reaver, not general build tips.

Answer (score 0):

Essence Reaver isn't just worth it, goldwise.

It has a very high cost, similar to the Bloodthirster and Botrk, but it doens't give % damage nor a shield.

And it's actually not that reliable , you do run out of mana while kiting with the Essence reaver. Not to mention that by that point in the game, if you don't have damage then your teamfights will be really screwed (hence why a Stattik or Infinity Edge would give you the well, edge)

If you want a mana item that is good on Ashe, while still scaling well troughout the game go for an early Tear of the Goddess (720 gold), which then can be built into a Muranamana which gives you damage, mana and mana regen.